# Quantmod: buildmodel command with Error

Tags: r, statistics, quantmod

When I use `quantmod` package there is a problem when I call `buildModel` command.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TSLA",from='2015-03-01')
q.model = specifyModel(Next(OpCl(TSLA)) ~ Lag(OpHi(TSLA),0:3),na.rm = T)
buildModel(q.model,method='lm',training.per=c('2015-09-01','2010-10-01'))
```

But there is is an error when I call `buildModel`

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Next.OpCl.TSLA' not found

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you define TSLA as a variable using `TSLA<-getSymbols("TSLA",from='2015-03-01')`?

Comment: @etienne  `getSymbols` defines `TSLA` in the global environment. You can check it running `ls()` after `getSymbols`. This will be changed in the next release of `quantmod`, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Pascal Ok thanks, didn't know that

Comment: You wrote `c('2015-09-01','2010-10-01')` in the training period. There is a typo. It should be `c('2015-09-01','2015-10-01')`.

Comment: REALLY stupid!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pascal pointed out, there is a typo in your function : use 2015 instead of 2010 for your second date:

```
buildModel(q.model,method='lm',training.per=c('2015-09-01','2015-10-01'))
                                                               ^
```

If the dates are in chronological order I haven't got the problem any longer :

```
quantmod object:   lm1446193179.60143   Build date:  2015-10-30 09:17:52 

Model Specified: 
     Next(OpCl(TSLA)) ~ Lag(OpHi(TSLA), 0:3) 

Model Target:  Next.OpCl.TSLA        Product:  TSLA 
Model Inputs:  Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.0, Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.1, Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.2, Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.3 

Fitted Model: 

    Modelling procedure:  lm 
    Training window:  22  observations from  2015-09-01 to 2015-10-01

Call:
lm(formula = quantmod@model.formula, data = training.data)

Coefficients:
            (Intercept)  Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.0  Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.1  
              -0.001594                -0.147112                -0.041063  
Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.2  Lag.OpHi.TSLA.0.3.Lag.3  
               0.261051                -0.023408
```